# Change App featured images after publishing at Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I am wondering if I can change some of the app images (like the screenshots, for example) when the app is already at the Android Market. I haven't published my app yet, and so I wanted to know beforehand.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  You just need to upload new ones and remove the old ones via the Developer Console.